# How to check the access token is valid or not without using appId and secret?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have an access token. I want to check the access token is valid or not using php-sdk. Is anyway to check the access token is valid or not ?

Comment: If this is an access token belonging to your own app, then you should _have_ app_id and app_secret; if it is _not_ – then what business is it of your’s whether or not it’s valid …?

Comment: it is possible to get user profile using the link https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN (with no appid or app secret) then how can i check the access token is valid or not using php-sdk ? @CBroe

Comment: By making exactly that API call for example …

Comment: @CBroe Can u provide an example php code for handling this. i am beginner.. please...

Comment: Look at the documentation and the examples within the PHP-SDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `access_token` can be used without using the App ID and Secret. You can simply make a API call to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx. If the `access_token` is valid, the user's information will be viewable. If the access_token is invalid you'll get an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Mar 13, 2014 5:00am. The current time is Mar 19, 2014 8:25am.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 463
   }
}
```